# Azure REST API - Create, through programming, a database within an elasticPoll

Tags: c#, json, azure

I need to create, through programming, a database in an elasticPoll.

To do this, I'm using the API version 2014-04-01, indicated in "Azure REST APIs > SQL Database > Databases > [Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/Databases/CreateOrUpdate#databases_createorupdate)".

I create a new HttpWebRequest object and launch the .Create() method

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{2}/databases/{3}?api-version={4}", VariabiliGlobali.SubscriptionID, VariabiliGlobali.ResourceGroup, VariabiliGlobali.SqlServerName, databaseName, VariabiliGlobali.APIVersion));
```

and compile the properties:

```
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer" + token;
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset = utf-8";
request.Method = "PUT"
```

I create a new StreamWriter object

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            //streamWriter.Close();
        }
```

and the .Write() mothod parameter, assign the complete Json code of the model shown in the "Databases - Create Or Update"  example as below.

```
            string json =
            "{" +
   "\"parameters\": {" +
        "\"subscriptionId\": \"" + VariabiliGlobali.SubscriptionID + "\"," +
        "\"resourceGroupName\": \"" + VariabiliGlobali.ResourceGroup + "\"," +
        "\"serverName\": \"" + VariabiliGlobali.SqlServerName + "\"," +
        "\"databaseName\": \"" + databaseName + "\"," +
        "\"api-version\": \"" + VariabiliGlobali.APIVersion + "\"," +
        "\"parameters\": {" +
                    "\"properties\": {" +
                "\"elasticPoolName\": \"" + elasticPoolName + "\"" +

            "}," +
                    "\"location\": \"West Europe\"" +

        "}" +
        "}," +
"\"responses\": {" +
            "\"200\": {" +
                "\"body\": {" +
                    "\"id\": \"/subscriptions/" + VariabiliGlobali.SubscriptionID + "/resourceGroups/" + VariabiliGlobali.ResourceGroup + "/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/" + VariabiliGlobali.SqlServerName + "/databases/" + databaseName + "\"," +
            "\"name\": \"" + databaseName + "\"," +
            "\"type\": \"Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases\"," +
            "\"location\": \"West Europe\"," +
            "\"kind\": \"v12.0,user\"," +
            "\"properties\": {" +
                        "\"edition\": \"Standard\"," +
                "\"status\": \"Online\"," +
            "\"serviceLevelObjective\": \"S0\"," +
            "\"collation\": \"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS\"," +
            "\"creationDate\": \"2017-02-24T22:39:46.547Z\"," +
            "\"maxSizeBytes\": \"268435456000\"," +
            "\"currentServiceObjectiveId\": \"f1173c43-91bd-4aaa-973c-54e79e15235b\"," +
            "\"requestedServiceObjectiveId\": \"f1173c43-91bd-4aaa-973c-54e79e15235b\"," +
            "\"requestedServiceObjectiveName\": \"S0\"," +
            "\"sampleName\": null," +
            "\"defaultSecondaryLocation\": \"Japan West\"," +
            "\"earliestRestoreDate\": \"2017-02-10T01:52:52.923Z\"," +
            "\"elasticPoolName\": null," +
            "\"containmentState\": 2," +
            "\"readScale\": \"Disabled\"," +
            "\"failoverGroupId\": null" +

            "}" +
                "}" +
            "}," +
    "\"201\": {" +
                "\"body\": {" +
                    "\"id\": \"/subscriptions/" + VariabiliGlobali.SubscriptionID + "/resourceGroups/" + VariabiliGlobali.ResourceGroup + "/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/" + VariabiliGlobali.SqlServerName + "/databases/" + databaseName + "\"," +
            "\"name\": \"" + databaseName + "\"," +
            "\"type\": \"Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases\"," +
            "\"location\": \"West Europe\"," +
            "\"kind\": \"v12.0,user\"," +
            "\"properties\": {" +
                                "\"edition\": \"Standard\"," +
                    "\"status\": \"Online\"," +
                    "\"serviceLevelObjective\": \"S0\"," +
                    "\"collation\": \"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS\"," +
                    "\"creationDate\": \"2017-02-24T22:39:46.547Z\"," +
                    "\"maxSizeBytes\": \"268435456000\"," +
                    "\"currentServiceObjectiveId\": \"f1173c43-91bd-4aaa-973c-54e79e15235b\"," +
                    "\"requestedServiceObjectiveId\": \"f1173c43-91bd-4aaa-973c-54e79e15235b\"," +
                    "\"requestedServiceObjectiveName\": \"S0\"," +
                    "\"sampleName\": null," +
                    "\"defaultSecondaryLocation\": \"Japan West\"," +
                    "\"earliestRestoreDate\": \"2017-02-10T01:52:52.923Z\"," +
                    "\"elasticPoolName\": null," +
                    "\"containmentState\": 2," +
                    "\"readScale\": \"Disabled\"," +
                    "\"failoverGroupId\": null" +

                "}" +
                "}" +
            "}," +
    "\"202\": { }" +
        "}" +
    "}";
```

Launch the .GetResponse() method of the HttpWebRequest object

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

and in response I get the following error:

```
{'Error': {"code": "InvalidRequestContent", "message": "The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member' parameters on object of type 'ResourceDefinition' , Line 1, position 14. '. "}}
```

Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JSON should only have `parameters` and not the `responses`. Can you please try by deleting everything except parameters in your request JSON?

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks. I tried with this JSON `{"parameters": {"subscriptionId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX","resourceGroupName": "XXXXXXX","serverName": "XXXXXXX","databaseName": "XXXXXXX","api-version": "2014-04-01","parameters": {"properties": {"elasticPoolName": "XXXXX"},"location": "West Europe"}},}` 
but I answered with the following error:
`{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'parameters' on object of type 'ResourceDefinition'. Path 'parameters', line 1, position 14.'."}}`

Comment: I believe the documentation is incorrect. Can you please try with the following JSON: `{"properties": {"elasticPoolName": "XXXXX"},"location": "West Europe"}`?

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the documentation is incorrect. Correct request payload should be:

```
{"properties": {"elasticPoolName": "XXXXX"},"location": "West Europe"}
```